# Django deployment with nginx, gunicorn without virtual enviroment

Tags: django, gunicorn, django-deployment

I have a django website which was hosted using one click app option at digitalocean.
Site gets good pageview and has grown bigger.

I am moving the site to new server and do not want to use one click application option to do everything manually.

I am not good at server part.

Following this tutorial. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

I am stuck on gunicorn part. Everything working fine till `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi`

Can some one help on these points:

- How to setup Gunicorn
- I am not using virtualenviroment

Project located at below directory:

```
>>home/django_project
```

Could not find a single solution on entire internet. Have hopes with experts here.

Comment: You can use uwsgi. https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html. And why don't you use a virtual environment?

Comment: I am not going to host any other django project on same server. So not planning to use VE.